# how to insert custom Javascripts in drupal 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal. I have converted Psd to html template after html to drupal theme. After converting all css files are working but javascript files are not working properly. For example javasccript code for navbar fix on top is like this

```js
(window).scroll(function(){
  var sticky = $('.menubar'),
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 586) sticky.addClass('fixed');
  else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

this code is working on normal template but not in drupal theme.Here is the libraries.ylm file

```html
lobal-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap.css: {}
      css/font-awesome.css: {}
      css/responsive-menu.min.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      
global-js:
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/jquery.singlePageNav.min.js: {} 
    js/responsive-menu.js: {} 
    js/customscript.js: {}    
  dependencies:
      - core/jquery
```

customscript.js is having all custom javascript code. Please help me.

Comment: Please, post your theme.info.yml

Comment: u need to attach somehow your library, check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512831/how-to-add-javascript-library-in-drupal-8-theme/40281342#40281342